# Can we customize the Google Plus native share dialogue box for ios?

Tags: ios, sdk, google-plus

In iOS5 the share dialogue box doesnt work fine, but in IOS 6 and 7 it works fine. In ios5 the dialogue box width is uneven and the close button and all is not shown properly. So it is pretty much difficult to interact with the window.

Comment: Officially the Google+ SDK only supports iOS 6 or higher.

Comment: @Hard_Soul Do you know how to get the GPlus iOS SDK to sign in within the app rather than via Safari?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but that isn't possible.

Comment: Do you know how to get the GPlus iOS SDK to sign in within the app rather than via Safari?

Comment: As you can see from: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in the default behaviour is to use (in order):
1- Google+ app (if installed)
2- Chrome for iOS (if installed)
3- Mobile Safari.